# PriorityQueue with frequently need to adjust the Comparator - How do I handle this best?

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator, dijkstra

I'm working on a Dijkstra algorithm for university using a PriorityQueue to store the remaining vertices of my graph, ordered by shortest traversal distance.
The Comparator I use:

```
class DistanceComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    int[] dist; 
    public DistanceComparator(int[] d) {
        dist = d;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer i, Integer j)
    {
        if((dist[i]-dist[j]) < 0) { 
            return -1;
        }
        if((dist[i]-dist[j]) > 0) { 
            return  1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that the distances are changing, so the Comparator of my queue would need to be updated frequently.

```
static PriorityQueue<Integer> refreshQueue(int[] d) {
    Comparator<Integer> comp = new DistanceComparator(d);
    PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(adj.length, comp);
    for(int i = 0; i < adj.length; i++) {
        q.add(i);
    }
    return q;
}
```

This does the trick, however it would also strain the required runtime `O(num Edges*log(num Vertices))`.

How can I eliminate the need to adjust the Comparator each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional way to implement Dijkstra's algorithm in Java is to create a separate class that contains a node and a distance:

```
class Dist implements Comparable<Dist> {
  final int vertex;
  final int distance;

  public int compareTo(Dist other) {
    return Integer.compare(distance, other.distance);
  }
}
```

and to put *those* into your priority queue.

You'll end up with out-of-date `Dist` objects reflecting a suboptimal path, but only after you've already seen the "optimal" path, so just ignore vertices you've already taken out from the priority queue.

Basically, don't change the `Comparator`: change the objects being compared.